# Should I be worried about this Error Log?

Tags: php

fairly simple question posted here. Basically recently I have been noticing very large error logs so when I opened it I found this exact line posted hundreds of times every time any PHP page is loaded it will post this into the error log just wondering if it's something I should be worried about and if so how to resolve this issue?

```
    [29-Mar-2016 00:35:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic 
library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo_mysql.so' 
- /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open 
shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: edit php.ini remove that load line or fix it.

Comment: @downvoter what is wrong with this question?

Comment: Will try and locate my php.ini and will try and fix the issue then thankyou. I was just wondering because my error logs were like 600mb just repeating this aha

Comment: `phpinfo();` will tell you where the file is

Comment: @Dagon thankyou very handy

Comment: While it doesn't necessarily matter because you apparently are not utilizing `PDO`, just make a note of you having disabled it for in the future. `PDO` is pretty broad and becoming more and more standard everyday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means the you told php to load `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo_mysql.so` but that file does not exist. Edit the php configuration file and point to the correct path or if you do not use PDO mysql delete it.